# input[type=text] Vs. class specificity

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My html text input element is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Ask</label>
  <input type="text" name="ask_question" class="form-control" id="ask-question">
</div>
```

There are two stylesheets 'A' and 'B' that try to modify this element.

A is loaded BEFORE B.

A specifies:

```
input[type=text] {
   blah;
   blah;
}
```

B Specifies:

```
.form-control {
  meh;
  meh;
}
```

Now, browser shows the styling from stylesheet 'A' instead of 'B'. Is there any way to ignore 'A' and use the styling from 'B'?

Note: Stylesheet 'B' is actually bootstrap.min.css which does not specify attribute styling and therefore, I'm unable to override the styling from 'A'. Would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: adding `!important` to css rules you want to override in stylesheet B should fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not want to edit the B style-sheet to make the rule more specific, you can edit the A style-sheet

a couple of workarounds

```
[type=text] { /*drop specificity so last rule wins, i do not think type=text is used anywhere else*/
   blah;
   blah;
}
```

or

```
input[type=text]:not(.form-control) { /*explicitly do not apply to .form-control*/
   blah;
   blah;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use !important. This forces the rule to override other rules on the same element.

```
.form-control {
  meh !important;
  meh !important;
}
```

Comment: ```!important``` is bad practice, try to avoid this. You'll realise how bad this is when you have to debug it